# Unit Test case for Repository in spring boot applicaiton

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I am bit confused with UnitTest and Integration Test
I know that below code is Integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = LavaMasterApplication.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class CurrencyServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyService currencyService;

    static CurrencyDTO currencyDTO = new CurrencyDTO();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        currencyDTO.setCode("INR");
        currencyDTO.setName("Indian Rupee");
        currencyDTO.setNumber(12);
    }

    @Test
    public void testA_addCurrency() {
        CurrencyDTO dto = currencyService.addCurrency(currencyDTO);
        assertThat(dto).isEqualTo(currencyDTO);
    }
}
```

How can I write unit test case for the same aproach like for repository or service. I tried with below snippet code which does not work.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CurrencyServiceImplUT {

    @Mock
    CurrencyRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testA_addCurrency() {
        Currency currency = new Currency();
        currency.setCode("IND");
        currency.setName("INDIA");
        currency.setNumber(1);
//        CurrencyRepository currencyRepository = mock(CurrencyRepository.class);
        when(repository.save(currency)).thenReturn(currency);
        List<Currency> all = repository.findAll();
        when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(null);

    }
}
```

Above code does not work, it returns null after saving entity and findAll() also null.

I need to write unit test case for repository and services

Comment: Why do you think that this is an integration test? But first simply read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing

Comment: Like @SimonMartinelli said read the documentation. To unit test you don't need to load all spring context. You could instantiate your service with your mocked objects using the service constructor (unit test). Or you could load all spring and test your service through an integration test.

Comment: I am looking for Unit test sample rather than documentation, I tend to get confusion while reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `CurrencyService` does and what you tried to do on the Unit Test example that you show to us, but the equivalent unit test of the integration test will be something like:

```
public class CurrencyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    CurrencyRepository repository; // mock the repository

    @InjectMocks
    CurrencyService service; // use the real implementation and inject the @Mock's on it

    @Test
    public void testA_addCurrency() {

        Currency currency = new Currency();
        currency.setCode("IND");
        currency.setName("INDIA");
        currency.setNumber(1);

        when(repository.save(currency)).thenReturn(currency); //mocking the repository return

        CurrencyDTO currencyDTO = new CurrencyDTO();
        currencyDTO.setCode("INR");
        currencyDTO.setName("Indian Rupee");
        currencyDTO.setNumber(12);

        CurrencyDTO dto = currencyService.addCurrency(currencyDTO);
        assertThat(dto).isEqualTo(currencyDTO);

    }
}
```

As I said, I can't tell if this test makes sense to you, but your unit test should follow this kind of code.